# Can I transfer data to premium version using ObjectInuptStream and ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: android

I am trying to find a means to transfer data from an android lite app to a premium one. I am trying to use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream, but I run into trouble because I have to have different package names due to google play restrictions, and then my custom objects aren't recognized. Is there any way around this, so that I can transfer my own objects directly? is there any other method you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest approach would be to let user export the data to SD card and then your premium/paid version of app should let him import this data.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did in the end. Cheers!